# Meaning of the word « veuch »

Tags: sens

I have seen this word on some French blogs relating to hair styling. I assume it is a colloquialism since it is not in any dictionaries. What does it mean?

Comment: You could have looked it up in [a dictionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/veuch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what is called [verlan](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlan) in french.
"Verlan" stands for "à l'envers", where you revert syllables.
So here "veuch" becomes "ch'veu", which is the short version of "cheveux" => "hair".

Comment: Often with Verlan, the last syllable is cut or dropped, especially if it ends with a vowel. *Moche* becomes *cheumo*, but the final 'o' is dropped. It makes "*cheum*". Same goes for : *Flic* > *keufli* > **keuf** and *femme* *meufa* > **meuf**